# Boarding greyhound bus along route

Tags: tickets, greyhound, new-york-state

I have a newbie question

I have Greyhound tickets from Toronto,ON to NYC.  The first stop on this route is Buffalo NY.

I have individual tickets for each leg of trip (e.g. Toronto–Buffalo,
Buffalo - Syracuse etc.).

My question is: Can I board the bus at Buffalo rather than at Toronto, as it turns out that works better with our trip plans?

(I Tried to contact Greyhound, but they are closed until Monday)

Comment: Contractually I don't know the answer. However practically I know you can. Greyhound boarding process is not by scanning a barcode. They just collect the printed ticket. I strongly doubt their system are like airline systems which void previous unflown legs.

Comment: Are they the same bus *route*?  Or are they different route numbers? Because if a driver on the same route knows you didn't get on in Toronto, he may give away your seat to a walk-up.  However if it's a different route, the next driver won't know that.

Comment: Did you buy this as a single ticket in a single transaction?

Comment: hi guys thanks for comments thus far Harper it is the same route number throughout .

Comment: carl ticket was purchased as one transaction but i have individual printed at home tickets for Toronto to Buffalo - Buffalo to Syracuse - Syracuse to New York NY As i am located in Australia my mother on my behalf contacted Toronto and they said i could board at buffalo. I am in the process of negotiating a change of departure date on tickets from 1st of Jan to the 31st December they are saying i can only change the date by visiting the departure point the day before but i worry there will be no seats left. I hope they are correct with boarding at buffalo. Thanks very much for help so far.